# Ubuntu delete count shows more files than initial count

Tags: files, git, delete, npm

I was deleting a git repo. I first cloned it and then did `npm i` to install the dependencies.

But, then soon after installation completed I had to delete the repo folder. I selected the folder and did `Shift+DEL`.

Here is what it shows while deleting. This screenshot was taken while deleting is still in progress.

Is this a bug or is it fine?

It has crossed around 11k files now, so I clicked the cancel button.

[image]

Edit: This folder is stored on my Local Disk.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the project was still live with a SASS compiler watch command. So as I deleted files maybe it kept compiling more files. I closed the terminal window and then deleted it.

Why did this happen?